# How to install Glc in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install Glc on Ubuntu Saucy 13.10 so far without luck.

How can I install it?

Comment: Can you edit your question with an explanation of what glc is? "GLC" isn't enough to search on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was no official glc package for "raring" and "saucy" in PPA repositories.So we need to edit the repository file for installing glc in Ubuntu 13.10,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:arand/ppa
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arand-ppa-saucy.list
```

change "saucy" to "precise" then save the file.Now run,

```
sudo apt-get update   
sudo apt-get install glc
```

Comment: That ppa is not for saucy

Comment: i updated my answer.